# CSS doesn't load after migrating a magento store

Tags: magento

I have a magento store "www.xyz.com". Now I have created a subdomain dev.xyz.com and copy all scripts and create a new database for subdomain.

I have done following things after migration:

1 - delete all cache files
2 - delete all session files
3 - change database details into local.xml
4 - update url into "core_config_data"

After updating these thing my frontend loaded without css and admin is not working.

Please help me Thanks in advance

Comment: if you mention your domain names exactly, that will help to findout reason

Comment: front end is working now by adding following RewriteRule

RewriteRule ^(index.php/)?dev/([^/]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ lib/dev/m.php?f=$3&d;=$

Now admin is not working url is

https://dev.primevaping.com/admin